# changing IP address of websphere installation

Tags: ip, hostname, migration, websphere

i am not a websphere expert.
we are migrating our websphere application to a different server (which has a different IP and hostname). we use WAS network deployment v 6.1. I came across some articles which describes the steps to change the hostname of the WAS installation but does not say anything about changing IP addresses.

[http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.websphere.nd.doc%2Finfo%2Fae%2Fae%2Ftagt_hostname.html](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/info/ae/ae/tagt_hostname.html)

There are few files such as plugin-cfg.xml file where I see the server IP is hard-coded. 
Is it like, after the new hosts file is placed in the server, changing the hostname through these steps and it will automatically update the IP addresses?

please advice.

Answer (score 1):

You can restore configuration of WAS to new server instead of changing hostname and IP. Commands are: `*backupConfig.sh*` and `*restoreConfig.sh*`.

Firstly you can install WAS 6.1 and create cells, profiles, nodes and servers. Do not configure them. Then restore your backup which is taken from old server. All the configurations and applications will be installed.

**But the key point is that, all the `*profile/cell/node/server*` names must be the same..**

Comment: @slm: we donot want to go with a new installation. just migrate (copy) the data filesystem and change the required files. pls assist.

Comment: @KannanLg - this isn't my answer, I just edited it, Tolqiu is the author of the answer.

Comment: slm: sry, didnt notice it.. :)

@Tolqiu: we donot want to go with a new installation. just migrate (copy) the data filesystem and change the required files. pls assist.